# How to convert text file into json file using powerShell

Tags: json, powershell

Below is the auto generated text file raw content.

```
Application Name: XKHGKSGHXSNBXS
Secret Key:       NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NmMyLWJlMzctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy=
Application Name: HVABSVGJCXJGsx
Secret Key:       OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MTc1MTk1ZTkz=
Application Name: khsxsvxhjvsGJJHJ
Secret Key:       NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NmMyLWJlMzctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy=
Application Name: HDFACVXJAGSV
Secret Key:       OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MTc1MTk1ZTkz=
Application Name: WCVDACsBHBHvsx
Secret Key:       NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NmMyLWJlMzctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy=
Application Name: 90GVASXSACVSA
Secret Key:       OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MTc1MTk1ZTkz=
Application Name: NBSANX0067Jtudent
Secret Key:       NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NmMyLWJlMzctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy=
Application Name: ABNSVXNBSXdfert
Secret Key:       OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MTc1MTk1ZTkz=
```

Now I want to convert this text file into json file using **powerShell.**

1> If we convert this directly using -ConvertToJson then it gives unwanted o/p.

2> If we convert text file into op1.csv and then again convert to op2.json it also gives unwanted o/p(output).

3> If we remove extra \tabs and Whitespaces from the file and then repeating the step 2 gives trash.

I want that o/p should be as follow.

```
[
  {
    "ApplicationName" : "POADFJBKJBHACBNASCVX",
    "SecretKey"       : "NDRkNDJjOTADFHACVJNmZTQy"
  },
  {
    "ApplicationName" : "NBFSVJBHACBNASCVX",
    "SecretKey"       : "NDRkNDJjOTADFHACVJNmZTQy"
  },
  {
    "ApplicationName" : "VDFACBHACBNASCVX",
    "SecretKey"       : "NDRkNDJjOTADFHACVJNmZTQy"
  },
  {
    "ApplicationName" : "ADFCASBKJBHACBNASCVX",
    "SecretKey"       : "NDRkNDJjOTADFHACVJNmZTQy"
  },
  {
    "ApplicationName" : "DFCKJBHACBNASCVX",
    "SecretKey"       : "NDRkNDJjOTADFHACVJNmZTQy"
  },
  {
    "ApplicationName" : "FERDBKJBHACBNASCVX",
    "SecretKey"       : "NDRkNDJjOTADFHACVJNmZTQy"
  },
  ...
]
```

**Note: there may be N number of blocks in Text File.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `switch -Regex -File` to loop over the lines in the file and create an object as you go. Finally, convert this array of objects to JSON:

```
# loop through the file line-by-line
$result = switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\AutoGeneratedFile.txt' {
    '^Application Name:.*' {
        $item = [PsCustomObject]@{ ApplicationName = ($_ -split ':', 2)[1].Trim(); SecretKey = '' }
    }
    '^Secret Key:.*' {
        $item.SecretKey = ($_ -split ':', 2)[1].Trim()
        # output the completed item
        $item
    }
}

# convert the array of objects to Json
$result | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "XKHGKSGHXSNBXS",
        "SecretKey":  "NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NmMyLWJlMzctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy="
    },
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "HVABSVGJCXJGsx",
        "SecretKey":  "OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MTc1MTk1ZTkz="
    },
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "khsxsvxhjvsGJJHJ",
        "SecretKey":  "NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NmMyLWJlMzctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy="
    },
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "HDFACVXJAGSV",
        "SecretKey":  "OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MTc1MTk1ZTkz="
    },
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "WCVDACsBHBHvsx",
        "SecretKey":  "NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NmMyLWJlMzctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy="
    },
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "90GVASXSACVSA",
        "SecretKey":  "OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MTc1MTk1ZTkz="
    },
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "NBSANX0067Jtudent",
        "SecretKey":  "NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NmMyLWJlMzctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy="
    },
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "ABNSVXNBSXdfert",
        "SecretKey":  "OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MTc1MTk1ZTkz="
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ConvertFrom-StringData` to create objects from reading two lines at a time. Those objects could then be converted to JSON.

```
Get-Content file.txt -ReadCount 2 | Foreach-Object {
    $hash = [ordered]@{}
    $_ -replace ':','=' | ConvertFrom-StringData | Foreach-Object { 
        $_.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
            $hash[$_.key] = $_.value
        }
    }
    [pscustomobject]$hash
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ConvertTo-Json Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility

```
ConvertTo-Json
              [-InputObject] <Object>
              [-Depth <Int32>]
              [-Compress][-EnumsAsStrings]
              [-AsArray]
              [-EscapeHandling <StringEscapeHandling>][<CommonParameters>]
```

Read more about it on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.1)